# A Necessary Condition for Measurable Sets

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable. I want to show that for any subset $A \subset E$ we have 
\begin{align*}
m(E) = m_*(A) + m^*(E \setminus A)
\end{align*}
where $m_*(A) = \sup\{m(\mathcal{C}) : \mathcal{C} \subset A \text{ is closed }\}$ and $m^*(A) = \inf \{m(\mathcal{O}): \mathcal{O}\supset A \text{ is open}\}$. My definition of measuribility is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open set $\mathcal{U} \supset E$ such that $\lambda^*(\mathcal{U} \setminus E) \leq \epsilon$.

I've solved it for the case $m(E) = 0$, so we can assume $E$ has nonzero measure. Any hints or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Fixing a typo. $A$ is suppose to be an arbitrary subset of $E$ not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your statement, it probably should read:

$$m(E)=m_*(A\cap E)+m^*(E\setminus A)$$

I will assume you have already proven that $m^*$ coincides with the outer measure defined in the usual sense. First note that, by monotonicity and sub-aditivity:

$$m_*(A\cap E)+m^*(E\setminus A)\le m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(E\setminus A)\le(E)$$

Now, if we knew that $m_*(G\cup F)\ge m_*(G) + m_*(F)$ for any subsets $F,G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then it would follow that:

$$m_*(A\cap E)+m^*(E\setminus A)\ge m_*(A \cap E)+m_*(E\setminus A)\ge m_*((A\cap E)\cup (E\setminus A))\ge m_*(E)$$

But, since $E$ is measurable, so is $E^c$, hence given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an open set $U \supset E^c$ such that $\lambda(U\setminus (E^c))\le \varepsilon$, this is $\lambda(E \cap U)\le \varepsilon$. But $U^c$ is closed and $E\subset U^c$, hence:

$$m_*(E)\le \lambda(E)=\lambda(E\cap U)+\lambda(E\setminus U) \le \varepsilon + \lambda (E\setminus U)\le \varepsilon + \lambda (U^c)\le \varepsilon + m_*(E)$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $m_*(E)=\lambda(E)$.

We have therefore reduce the original problem to proving that $m_*(G\cup F)\ge m_*(G) + m_*(F)$ for any subsets $F,G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I leave this to you, you can also find the proof in Halmos' *Measure Theory*, in the section on inner measures.

Comment: You mean $m_*(G\cup F) \geq m_*(G)+m_*(F)$ for any disjoint $F,G$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the typo. I'm confused as to how one has $m^*(E) \geq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(E\setminus A)$ from monotinicity and subadditivity.  Shouldn't monotinicity and subadditivity give you the reverse inequality since $E = (E \cap A) \cup (E \setminus A)$?